# Simplest Javascript If-statement not working

Tags: php, javascript, if-statement

I want to check a php variable in javascript and create an Array accordingly.

I tried this, but it's not working:

```
<script language="Javascript" type="text/javascript">
            var phpvar1_large = <?php echo $var1_large ?>; 
            var phpvar2_large = <?php echo $var2_large ?>; 
            var phpvar3_large = <?php echo $var3_large ?>; 
            var phpvar4_large = <?php echo $var4_large ?>; 

            if(!phpvar1_large){
            var imgArray = new Array(
                '<?=$main_img; ?>'
                );
            }else if(!phpvar2_large){
                var imgArray = new Array(
                '<?=$main_img; ?>',
                '<?=$var1_large; ?>'
                );
            }else if(!phpvar3_large){
            var imgArray = new Array(
                '<?=$main_img; ?>',
                '<?=$var1_large; ?>',
                '<?=$var2_large; ?>',
                '<?=$var3_large; ?>'
                );
            }else if(!phpvar4_large){
                var imgArray = new Array(
                '<?=$main_img; ?>',
                '<?=$var1_large; ?>',
                '<?=$var2_large; ?>',
                '<?=$var3_large; ?>'
                );
            }else if(phpvar4_large){
            var imgArray = new Array(
                '<?=$main_img; ?>',
                '<?=$var1_large; ?>',
                '<?=$var2_large; ?>',
                '<?=$var3_large; ?>',
                '<?=$var4_large; ?>'
            );
            }
</script>
```

However, if I don't use an if-statement, the array is created correctly:

```
<script language="Javascript" type="text/javascript">
            var imgArray = new Array(
                '<?=$main_img; ?>',
                '<?=$var1_large; ?>',
                '<?=$var2_large; ?>',
                '<?=$var3_large; ?>',
                '<?=$var4_large; ?>'
            );
</script>
```

I appreciate your help very much!

Comment: Please post the generated HTML, not the PHP.

Comment: A switch case is more semantically appropriate in this context

Comment: @Asad, No way would a switch case be appropriate here.  Simply dealing with a proper array in the first place is the way to go.

Comment: You really should handle these conditions serverside

Comment: @Brad The switch construct is specifically designed for when a different set of statements needs to be executed based on the value of a single variable. It **is** more semantically appropriate that using multiple if/elseifs. This has nothing to do with whether he should use a proper array, which I agree with.

Comment: @Asad, Yes, I agree with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure your problem is that the boolean values you are writing via php are not being interpreted as boolean but strings, that is why it is always evalued as false.

you should write `var phpvar1_large = <?php echo json_encode($var1_large); ?>;`

You are welcome!

Answer (score 3):

I strongly recommend simply JSON-encoding your array.

```
$imgArray = array('img1.jpg', 'img2.jpg', etc);
echo 'var imgArray = ' . json_encode($imgArray);
```